# What is the meaning of " 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable "?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I want to create an array, k of dimention N X 1 where in MATLAB I have

```
N = 2^15
dx = 0.1
k = [0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1]'*2*pi/(N*dx)
```

In Python, I can create an array 1XN but I can't "flip it" (In MATLAB, one uses " ' ") . Here's my attempt:

```
N = 2**15
dx = 0.1
k = ( 2 * np.pi / (N * dx))*((np.arange(0, N/2-1),
                        np.array([0]),
                        np.arange(-N/2+1, -1))).reshape(1, N)
```

This is also sometimes accompanied by the error:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

What is going on here?

Comment: This error means that you are trying to call a value that is not a function or a class. For example `foo = 'bar'; foo()` will give the same error. If you get this error and you don't know why, you should simplify your code.  Kernighan’s law: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." You don't have to do all your operations in one line.

Comment: Goodness I'm not sure what I've done here. Is it an extra pair of brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I (and others) explained that MATLAB matrices are always 2d, and thus the `'` flip/transpose can change a (1,N) matrix to (N,1).  `np.arange(...)` makes a 1d array, **NOT** a 2d one.

Take your numpy expression in pieces:

```
In [212]: k=((np.arange(0, N/2-1),
     ...:   np.array([0]),
     ...:   np.arange(-N/2+1, -1)))
In [213]: type(k)
Out[213]: tuple
In [214]: len(k)
Out[214]: 3
In [215]: [i.shape for i in k]
Out[215]: [(16383,), (1,), (16382,)]
```

You can't `reshape` a tuple.  In

`arange` is perfectly happy with negative start value; no need to build this convoluted tuple:

```
In [217]: n
Out[217]: 16384
In [218]: k=np.arange(-n+1, n-1)
In [219]: k.shape
Out[219]: (32766,)
```

and you can make a "column" vector easily with (I must be repeating myself here):

```
In [220]: k[:,None].shape
Out[220]: (32766, 1)
In [221]: k.reshape(-1,1).shape
Out[221]: (32766, 1)
```

Your MATLAB expression

```
>> k = [0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1]'*2*pi/(N*dx) ;
>> size(k)
ans =

   32768       1
```

you can join matrices by simply putting them side by side
>> size([k,k])
ans =

```
   32768       2
```

In python that does not work.  In the first expression `(.,..)` makes a tuple, no a larger array.  `arrays` are joined with functions like `concatenate`.  Didn't I give you a link to a MATLAB differences page in a previous answer?

A 'callable' is generalized term for a `function`.  In python functions are called with `func(args)`.  MATLAB also does that, but it also uses () for indexing.  A numpy array can be indexed, but can't be treated as a function.